# Call URL Name From Another App In Django using Pattern Name + RedirectVew

Tags: python, django, redirect

I'm working on some redirects for a few URL paths.

I ended up needing to move a few of my paths to another APP.

I'm having an issue calling the pattern name to reference the other URL in my RedirectView.  Here's the url i'm trying to redirect which resides in a 'deals' app:

```
 path('<slug:slug>/', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='deal_detail', permanent=False))
```

Note i'm also importing the views from the referenced app like so:

`from dealmazing.views import *`

The new url that I want it to redirect to is in my core app directory and looks like this:

```
path('<slug:slug>/', deal_by_detail, name='deal_detail'),
```

Issue is that I'm getting this error:

`Reverse for 'deal_detail' not found. 'deal_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Is it not possible to reference an external pattern_name?

### UPDATE

My new URL's are working correctly after adding 'dealmazing' to my url pattern_name--but one issue.

here is code in my 'deals' app

`path('<slug:slug>/', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='dealmazing:deal_detail', permanent=False)),`

and the url path in my 'dealmazing' app

`path('<slug:slug>/', deal_by_detail, name='deal_detail'),`

If if go to the old link, i get a `'dealmazing' is not a registered namespace` error. Note I had no app_name or namespace set in my dealmazing urls file.  I tried that and still not working. This is error I'm getting:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  74.                 extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]

During handling of the above exception ('dealmazing'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in get
  180.         url = self.get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in get_redirect_url
  170.             url = reverse(self.pattern_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  84.                     raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /deals/steak-fries-beer-only-999-walkabout-wednesday/
Exception Value: 'dealmazing' is not a registered namespace
```

here is my deals URLS file:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from .views import *
from dealmazing.urls import *
from dealmazing.views import *
from deals.views import DealListView
from django.conf import settings

app_name = "deals"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Home.as_view(), name="deals"),
    path('latest-deals', DealListView.as_view(), name="latest-deals"),
    path('hot-deals', DealHotView.as_view(), name="hot-deals"),
    path('results/', search, name='deal-search'),
    path('category/<str:category>', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='dealmazing:category', permanent=False)),
    path('<slug:slug>/', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='dealmazing:deal_detail', permanent=False)),
    path('<int:pk>/like', like, name='like'),
    path('<int:pk>/favorite', favorite, name='favorite'),
    path('<int:pk>/remove_favorite', remove_favorite, name='remove_favorite'),
]
```

and my core (dealmazing) urls file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .sitemaps import *
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import *
from django.conf import settings
from deals.models import Deal
from deals.views import *

from django.conf.urls.static import static

sitemaps = {
    'static': StaticViewSitemap,
    'blog': BlogSitemap,
    'blog-category': BlogCategorySitemap,
    'deals': DealSitemap,
    'deals-category': DealCategorySitemap,
    'retailers': RetailerSitemap
}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name="home"),
    url(r'^oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^blog/', include("blog.urls", namespace="blog")),
    url(r'^accounts/', include("accounts.urls", namespace="accounts")),
    url(r'^about/', about, name="about"),
    url(r'^contact/', contact, name="contact"),
    url(r'^disclosure/', disclosure, name="disclosure"),
    url(r'^terms/', terms, name="terms"),
    url(r'^privacy/', privacy, name="privacy"),
    url(r'^submit_deal/', submit_deal, name="submit_deal"),
    url(r'^thanks/', thanks, name="thanks"),
    url(r"^deals/", include("deals.urls", namespace="deals")),
    path('<slug:slug>/', deal_by_detail, name='deal_detail'),
    path('deals/<slug:slug>', deals_by_retailer, name='retailer'),
    path('category/<str:category>', deals_by_category, name='category'),
    url(r"^newsletter/", include("newsletters.urls", namespace="newsletter")),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^robots.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="robots.txt", content_type="text/plain"), name="robots_file"),
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap,
         {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
         name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
] 

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set `app_name` in your `core/urls.py` or set a namespace when including the urls then you'll need to include this. For example:

```
path('<slug:slug>/', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='core:deal_detail', permanent=False))
```

Comment: hey @alasdair one quick question---my urls appear to be working, but if i visit one of the old links it doesn't redirect and shows as 'dealmazing' is not a registered namespace----now in my dealmazing urls file (my core) i don't have app_name or namespace set--would doing one of those fix this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what's going on from the comment. It's much easier to see the actual code rather than a description of the code. If you haven't set `app_name` or `namespace`, then adding a namespace as I've suggested isn't going to help.

Comment: sorry about that--i just added all of the information above after UPDATE--hope this helps you understand me a bit better

Comment: As I said, if you haven't set `app_name` or `namespace`, then my suggestion to use `'dealmazing:deal_detail'` isn't going to work. I'm still not clear what your URL patterns you have in which files, or how you include them.

Comment: ahh..ok, hmm.. i added my two urls files if it helps any

Comment: NEVER MIND- I'm good!  So, i removed that dealmazing namespace from the redirect...and fixed up all of the references in my templates and it works fine now..ugh sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I've got no idea what the issue was, because my suggestion to add the namespace wasn't the answer in this case. Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, compared with proper dependency of the folders

```
/My_Project
./apps
    ../api
    ../core
    ../other_app
```

In  api/apps.py  and other apps.py add:

```
class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    label='api'
    name = 'apps.api'
```

in api/urls

```
app_name='apps.api'

...
path('path/',api_views.ApiView.as_view(), name='some-view'),
...
```

in My_project urls:

```
 path('base-path/',RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='apps.api:some-view'), 
 name='redirect-view'),
```

in settings.py in Installed Apps

```
...
##  Local Apps
'apps.core',
'apps.api',
...
```